# JqueryMobile dynamic css not rendering

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a 2 pages in a document. The active page displays a list and on click on the list, I display the second page. The **`content`** div of the second page is dynamically added along with some custom css in the JS. The below Java script does this job, but I am not able to get the css render.

```
   $("#showmore").live("click", function(event, param1){       
        getUrl = $(this).attr('data-href');
        $.post(getUrl, function(data){  
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); 
            $('#more').html(data);
            $.mobile.activePage.page().trigger('refresh');
        });    
    });
```

I also tried `$.mobile.activePage.trigger('create');` .This works, but I go back and forth the two pages. But when i click on the list the second time the contents does not get rendered at all. Its a blank page with just the header!

Can anyone share your expertise on how I can go about adding dynamic contents with css to a secondary page and display it as many times I want to from the same page?

Comment: im looking for the same answer i think.  I am trying to change the background of a single list item.  JQM adds their CSS classes after mine, thereby overriding them.

Comment: @Mike_G When jQuery Mobile adds the classes when it initializes widgets, your classes are not removed. That gives you the ability to either use `!important` in your CSS declaration or you could make more specific CSS rules so they are used over the jQuery Mobile classes: `.ui-mobile .ui-page .ui-content .ui-listview .ui-li .ui-btn { color : hot-pink; }`... for example will override the jQuery Mobile styles because it is so specific (but will work for all buttons inside list-view list-items inside the content section inside a pseudo-page inside a jQuery Mobile webpage).

Comment: thank you so much for the tip jasper!

Answer (score 1):

You only need to call `.trigger('create')` on the elements you are replacing:

```
$("#showmore").live("click", function(event, param1){       
    var getUrl = $(this).attr('data-href');//don't unnecessarily create global vars
    $.post(getUrl, function(data){  
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

        //since you are only changing this HTML, you only have to initialize this HTML
        $('#more').html(data).trigger('create');
    });    
});
```

I've run into situations where this didn't seem to work but I had success initializing each type of widget separately like so:

```
$("#showmore").live("click", function(event, param1){       
    var getUrl = $(this).attr('data-href');//don't unnecessarily create global vars
    $.post(getUrl, function(data){  
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

        $('#more').html(data).find('a[data-role="button"]').button().end()
                             .find('ul[data-role="listview"], ol[data-role="listview"]').listview().end()
                             ...
    });    
});
```

Here is a demonstration of dynamically adding HTML to the DOM and then having jQuery Mobile initialize the widgets in the HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/csKtX/

Also, make sure you are adding the `data-role="button"` (etc.) to the widgets so jQuery Mobile knows to initialize them (my code from above assumes you've done this).

Comment: I even tired creating element like you are suggesing. This time none of the dynamic contents are showing up. Here is the page code into which i am trying to inject the `content`.  ` <div data-role="page" class="type-interior"  id="page-details">
<div data-role="content" id="more">
</div>
</div> `

Comment: @user1339736 I added a demo to my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/csKtX/. See if that helps you figure out your issue. Make sure you are adding the correct `data-role` attribute values to the widgets, my code expects those `data-attributes` to exist.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to figure out. I tried triggering the changed element and also the find. Interesting the find did not apply the css. But both approach only worked the first time. When I get back to this same page by page transition, the page contents is blank. Part of the dynamic content is a link to transition the page to the initial page. From the initial page I am going back to the new page. I will look further in the example code that you have provided and look at my code and see what I may be doing incorrectly.

Comment: In your jsfiddle example, everything happens on the same page. There is no page transition happening. In the list that I have I am changing to the second page with dynamic content and switch back to the initial page with the list. So the situation in the jsfiddle example is different from what I have.

Comment: @user1339736 The jQuery Mobile widget initialization/refresh does work pretty well, you've just got to massage your code into the proper format. Here's an updated JSFiddle to show that you can add dynamic content anytime: http://jsfiddle.net/csKtX/3/ (any no, this does not use AJAX, but I can tell you that it's functionally the same so the fact I'm not using AJAX shouldn't play into your situation).

Comment: Well apparently I couldn't get this to work. I redesigned the approach to show the dynamic data in one page itself as a different content div. This works. I simply had to display some information with some css. Your comment about `.trigger('create')` allowed me to refocus on the approach. I could understand part of  $('#home').children('.ui-content').append('<a data-role="button" href="#">Me, I am a button!</a>').find('a[data-role="button"]').not('.ui-btn').button();, but not all of it. Could you translate this for me, especially .not() and the .button()? Thanks.

Comment: @user1339736 `.button()` is the jQuery Mobile button initialization function, `.listview()` it the same but for list-view widgets. `.not('.ui-listview')` removes any already initialized widgets from the selection (because initialized list-view widgets are given the `.ui-listview` class). If you try to initialize an already initialized widget you'll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience wtih jQuery recently where dynamic content was not rendering in Firefox.  I got my site working and I think the problem may be with this line:
$('#more').html(data);

Try replacing it with an innerHTML method and see if that works.

Cheers

Comment: jQuery uses `.innerHTML` internally when you use the `.html()` function if `.innerHTML` is supported in the browser.

Comment: This I know, but after I narrowed it down to to any/all usage of .html(), using .innerHTML fixed it.  If I ever have some free time I might even try to figure out why.